# How to clear nested setInterval inside setTimeout

Tags: javascript

this is my code, which works but i don't know how to clear timeout and clearinterval

```
setTimeout(function(){
    setInterval( function(){
        if (Math.random()> 0.1){
            countdown.extendTimer(-3)
            console.log("im dying")
        }
    }, 1000)
}, 10000)
```

this is what i have tried, but the diseaseInterval() just starts immediately without waiting for 5 sec

```
function diseaseInterval(){
    if (Math.random()> 0.1){
        countdown.extendTimer(-3)
        console.log("im dying")
    }
}

function diseaseTimeout(){
    setInterval( diseaseInterval(),1000)
}

var onDisease = setTimeout(diseaseInterval(),5000)
```

This time i tried clearInterval inside clearTimeout itself, but it still doesn't work

```
var onDisease = setTimeout(function(){
    disease = true;
    var diseaseInterval = setInterval( function(){
        if (Math.random()> 0.1){
            countdown.extendTimer(-3)
            console.log("im dying")}
        else if (disease=false) {
            clearInterval(diseaseInterval);
        }
    }, 1000)
}, 10000)

function cure(){
    clearTimeout(onDisease);
    disease = false
}
```

Comment: check this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JOZKGR?editors=0012 hope this helps!

Comment: setInterval( diseaseInterval,1000) - diseaseInterval without ()

Comment: the same here setTimeout(diseaseInterval, 5000)